# adb sideload Throws error: closed on Nexus 6

Tags: adb, side-loading

I am trying to sideload the Android Marshallow OTA on my Nexus 6 using `adb sideload "<android marshmallow OTA>.zip"`, but the console keeps printing out `error: closed` with no success. I verified that I have enabled USB debugging, but this is still a problem. I have tried running `adb usb` as well as `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` as well as rebooting the phone to resolve this, but so far, no luck. I have also tried unlock the bootloader, although that did not seem to help.

The phone's Android Build Number is `LMY48T` (Android Lollipop 5.1.1)

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 on the machine on which I am trying to do this.

Comment: Does `adb devices` list your device? Proper adb drivers installed?

Comment: @Manubhargav Yes, `adb devices` does list the device, and I do have the proper adb drivers installed.

Comment: Before you executed `adb sideload` command, did you explicitly enable sideload option in your recovery? Which recovery are you using?

Comment: @Firelord I am using stock recovery.

Comment: @Firelord I feel like an idiot now. I haven't been able to do this because for some reason, my phone would lose its connection to my computer after executing `adb devices`. Pulling the connection and plugging it back in seems to resolve the problem. To answer the first part of your question, yes, I had selected the sideload option when trying to do this.